# Python - iterate through an entire list and assign it to a dict

Tags: python

```
text = "This is a test for my program"
new_dict = {}
text_list = text.split()

word_tester = 2
for word in text_list:
    word_tester = len(word)
    if len(word) == word_tester:
        new_dict[word_tester] = word

return new_dict
```

I am trying to build a program in python that goes through a list of strings and assigns them to a dict where the key is the amount of characters in that string and the value is the word itself
(eg: 2 : be, to 3 : foo, bar). My program however only goes through and assigns some of the given list of strings. What can I do to get this to work?

Comment: A dictionary can only hold one value for each key but this value can itself be e.g. a list.

Comment: I don't see the point of having `word_tester` as well as the inner `if`. Maybe you missed the fact that you're currently handling only words in length of 2 ?

Comment: one problem with your code is that you have `word_tester = len(word)` immediately followed by `if len(word) == word_tester`. In this case `len(word)` will always equal `word_tester` because you just made them equal on the previous line! You probably want to use another variable to track the word length.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to be sure to split on the space. I ran this, and it works.

```
text = "This is a test for my program"
text_list = text.split(" ")
new_dict = {}
for word in text_list:
    if len(word) in new_dict and word not in new_dict[len(word)]:
        new_dict[len(word)].append(word)
    else:
        new_dict[len(word)] = [word]

#print(new_dict)
#{1: ['a'], 2: ['is', 'my'], 3: ['for'], 4: ['This', 'test'], 7: ['program']}
return new_dict
```

Comment: I don't think you need to check if the word is in new_dict but you essentially beat me to the idea +1

Comment: if you are concerned with duplicates, using a `set` instead of a `list` and `add` instead of `append` will let you handle that without that check

Answer (score 0):

```
#1

text = "This is a test for my program"
final_dct = {len(word):word for word in text.split() if len(word)==len(word_tester)}

#2
text = "This is a test for my program"
new_dict = {}
text_list = text.split()


for word in text_list:
    if len(word) in new_dict and word not in new_dict[len(word)]:
        new_dict[len(word)].append(word)
    else:
        new_dict[len(word)] = [word]

return new_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be as simple as:

```
for word in text_list:
    new_dict[len(word)] = word
```

Note that in this dictionary, the key 4 is assigned to test, not this, because only one value can be assigned per key. To make the value a list in this case, you could use:

```
for word in text_list:
    if len(word) in new_dict:
        new_dict[len(word)].append(word)
    else:
        new_dict[len(word)] = [word]
```

Comment: this will retain only last word-length occurrences. so new_dict will have 'my' and skip 'is'.

Comment: Right... I'm working on that... Not clear what the OP expects but I assume a list in that case

Comment: @Mokshyam ok it should be fixed now

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a key can only have one value so you overwrite it every time you have a word with a given length. To remedy this you could store a list of strings as the dictionary value instead of a single string, as suggested in another example.

One handy tool from the `collections` module is the `defaultdict`, which lets you define a default entry if a key doesn't already have a value. A common use case is to start keys out with an empty list using `defaultdict(list)`. This saves you from having to check if a key doesn't exist yet and initializing it to an empty list manually. Incorporating this into your example, you would get:

```
from collections import defaultdict

text = "This is a test for my program"
new_dict = defaultdict(list) # a dictionary whose default value is an empty list
text_list = text.split()

for word in text_list:
    # append this word to the list of words with the same length
    new_dict[len(word)].append(word)

return new_dict
```

Comment: and if you don't care about storing duplicates, you can use a `set` to only store unique words: replace `defaultdict(list)` with `defaultdict(set)`and `new_dict[len(word)].append(word)` with `new_dict[len(word)].add(word)`. You can call `add` multiple times with the same string and only one instance will be stored in the set.